# TargetParameterCountException when creating an event in Facebook using the C# API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the [C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) to post an event. I've filled out basic event parameters, and have tested these parameters with the Graph API explorer. When I call PostTaskAsync, however:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "name", "Random" },
        { "start_time", "2012-11-11" },
    };

fb.PostTaskAsync("me/events", parameters);
```

I'm hit with a TargetParameterCountException. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FB changing something, again?

Answer (score 5):

The Facebook c# sdk expects the type implementing interface

```
IDictionary<string, object>
```

See the FacebookClient.cs file in sdk version 6.4.2. Inside the ToDictionary() method there is a cast:

```
var dictionary = parameters as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

This cast produces null and the sdk cannot convert your dictionary type to the dictionary type expected.

Change the code to new up your dictionary to the correct type and your code ought to work!